# 403 error from jQuery Ajax (but not from XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two Ajax calls, one using XMLHttpRequest and one using jQuery.  The first one completes successfully.  The second appears to complete successfully (the success function is called), but ends by throwing a 403 error.

The code for the XMLHttpRequest (that works) is:

```
function myfunction() {

    var apikey = document.getElementById( "apikey" ).value;
    var username = document.getElementById( "username" ).value;
    var password = document.getElementById( "password" ).value;

    xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4 ) {
            if ( xmlHttpReq.status == 200 ) {
                document.getElementById( "results" ).textContent = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
                alert(xmlHttpReq.responseText);
            }
            else {
                alert( xmlHttpReq.statusText );
            }
        } 
    }

    xmlHttpReq.open( "POST" , url , true );
    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader( "x-api-key" , apikey );
    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,OPTIONS");
    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,x-api-key,X-Amz-Security-Token" );
    xmlHttpReq.send( '{ "username" : "' + username + '" , "password" : "' + password + '" }' );

}
```

The code for the jQuery that returns a 403 error is:

```
$( "#jquerySubmit" ).click( function() {

    var apikey = $( "#apikey" ).val();
    var username = $( "#username" ).val();
    var password = $( "#password" ).val();

    var dataObject = '{ "username" : "' + username + '" , "password" : "' + password + '"}';

    $.ajax( { url : url , 
              type : 'POST' ,
              dataType: 'json' ,
              headers : {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "*" ,
                'x-api-key' : apikey ,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST,OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,x-api-key,X-Amz-Security-Token'
              },
              success: function (result) {
                    alert( result.body );
              },
              error: function (error) {
                    alert( error.responseText );
              },
              data : dataObject
    } );
});
```

The success alert statement **successfully fires** and **displays the expected results**, but then throws the 403 error.

Can anyone see an problem?

Comment: FYI `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are set by the server not the client, so setting those in your ajax request will not have any effect

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A 403 error is likely that it's not receiving the username/password correctly.  This is probably because you are setting up the the `dataObject` correctly.  In this context, it should be set up like a query string and not a JSON object.

Instead of this:

```
var dataObject = '{ "username" : "' + username + '" , "password" : "' + password + '"}';
```

Try this:

```
var dataObject = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
```

Or, if you want to be fancy, use jquery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
var dataObject = $("#username,#password").serialize();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  When I tried the two, both resulted in the failure function being called - saying the JSON couldn't be parsed in the web service.  Using the original method, I am able to see the expected results successfully returned (I'm simply echoing the username/password) in the result object.  But after displaying the expected results, I get the 403 error.

Comment: When result is returned with the expected data, is that response status 403? Or is a second ajax call being performed after the results are displayed?

Comment: It sounds like somehow a second call to the server is being made, resulting in the 403 error.  Is the call being triggered by a form element with a submit button click? You may need to `return false;` at the end of your method and/or accept an event parameter to your click handler and do `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the form from submitting along with the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I had my username and password input elements within a form.  So the Ajax call was submitted and finishing successfully.  Then, the form was being submitted and didn't have the x-api-key header, so it was failing.